# How can I add another information in an fetch API array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, recharts

So I'm trying to create a BarChart for the category, and each category will have a respective color. I map this information from the MongoDB.

```
  const [topDepartment,setTopDepartment] = useState([])
  useEffect(() =>{
   
    const getTopDepartment = async () =>{ 
      try {
        const res = await publicRequest.get(`/order/departments`)
        setTopDepartment(res.data)
        setLoading(false)
      } catch (error) {
        
      }
    }
    getTopDepartment()

  },[setTopDepartment])
```

This is the data I received

```
[
    {
        "total": 4,
        "category": "CAHS"

    },
    {
        "total": 2,
        "category": "CEIS"
    }
]
```

So what I'm trying to accomplish right now is , how can I add another information inside the objects, like this.

```
 const updatedData =  [
    {
        "total": 4,
        "category": "CAHS"
        "color": "purple"

    },
    {
        "total": 2,
        "category": "CEIS"
        "color": "green"

    }
]
```

Like in this image, the Bar will change it's color depending on its category
[image]

Comment: Is `const res` the data? If so change it to `let res` (might not even need to do this) and just update each index to whatever color you want.

Comment: If you knew your categories before, you could iterate your response array and have a check for category and add entry of color, if it is just random color you could give anything you want

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the array in map function and add another property to the object

```
const resWithColors = res.data.map((object) => {
   switch(object.category){
     case 'CEIS':
        object['color'] = "green";
        break;
     .
     .
     .
     default: 
       object['color'] = "red";
   }
   return object;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop over the data you recieved and add colors accordingly,

```
const updatedData = res.data.map(el => {
    el.color = "green"
    return el;
});
```

You can also add the color conditionally inside the map